Equivalent characterizations of finite sets
How can we show that the following notions of finiteness for a nonempty set $X$ are equivalent?

There exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that there is an injection $X \hookrightarrow \{1, \ldots, n\}$

There exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that there is no injection $\{1, \ldots, n\} \hookrightarrow X$

There exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that there is a surjection $\{1, \ldots, n\} \twoheadrightarrow X$

There exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that there is no surjection $X \twoheadrightarrow \{1, \ldots, n\}$

There exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that there is a bijection $X \leftrightarrow \{1, \ldots, n\}$


(5.) $\Rightarrow$ (1.) and (5.) $\Rightarrow$ (3.) are clear.
I think I can show the following:
(1.) $\Rightarrow$ (2.): By contradiction. Let $f: X \hookrightarrow \{1, \ldots, n\}$ be an injection. Assume that for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$, there is an injection $\{1, \ldots, m\} \hookrightarrow X$. In particular, take $m = n + 1$ and let $g: \{1, \ldots, n + 1\} \hookrightarrow X$ be an injection. Then $f \circ g: \{1, \ldots, n + 1\} \hookrightarrow \{1, \ldots, n\}$ is an injection, which is a contradiction.
(3.) $\Rightarrow$ (4.): By contradiction. Let $f: \{1, \ldots, n\} \twoheadrightarrow X$ be a surjection. Assume that for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$, there is a surjection $X \twoheadrightarrow \{1, \ldots, m\}$. In particular, let $m = n + 1$ and let $g: X \twoheadrightarrow \{1, \ldots, n + 1\}$ be a surjection. Then $g \circ f: \{1, \ldots, n\} \twoheadrightarrow \{1, \ldots, n + 1\}$ is a surjection, which is a contradiction.

You can show (2.) $\implies$ (5.) using the well-ordered property of $\mathbb{N}$.
If (2.) is true, by well-order there is a smallest $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with no possible injection $\{1, \ldots, n\} \to X$. Note, $n \neq 0$ because the empty function $\emptyset \to X$ is vacuously injective. Hence, $m = n - 1 \in \mathbb{N}$ exists. By construction, there is an injection $i : \{1, \ldots, m\} \to X$. In fact, $i$ is also a bijection. Otherwise, for a contradiction, there would be $x \in X$ that $i$ doesn't map to. Hence, you could define an injection $i^\ast : \{1, \ldots, m, m + 1 = n\} \to X$
$$
i^\ast(u) = \begin{cases} i(u) &u \in \{1, \ldots, m\} \\ x &u = n \end{cases}
$$ But this is not supposed to be possible. Hence, $i$ must be bijective i.e. (5.) is true.
Use a similar trick for (4.) $\implies$ (5.)
